# Gaps in wood floor near heating register

Tags: wood, heating, floor, crack

I have a maple floor that is showing gaps near the heating register. Looks like the wood is drying out due to the heat and shrinking. Is there any way to reduce this? Some sort of thermal barrier between the metal of the register and the wood?[image]

Comment: It probably has more to do with the dryness of the air outside the vent than actual heat exchange between the vent and the floor. Perhaps replacing the vent with something that directs the air away from the floor might help. Not sure how you could fix it at this point except by somehow increasing the humidity around that area.

Comment: The vent is about 3/4 closed, but I suspect you're right, the warmer, drier air is also contributing to the shrinkage. There is some wood under the register and i wonder how to best shield the floor from the warm air. Foil tape?

Comment: Moving the grate up a little to provide an air gap would be better. Maybe with a little thing foam sponge material to keep the dirt out.

Comment: However, if it were just contact heat I would expect to see more local shrinkage / discolouration near the register. That image looks like the boards are shrinking feet away from the register which makes me think air, not contact.

Comment: BTW is that floor "finished". Sealed I mean, it's hard to tell in the image.

Comment: Yes, it's finished.